# Peoplsoft WSDL not having User Id password authentication header

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, peoplesoft

I have created Peoplesoft WSDL using CI as service. In operation definition select userid and password. WSDL showing userid and password tags. But in SOAP UI header is still blank. Is it we have only add header manually it will not come automatically in WSDL request. if it is then what steps to be taken?

Comment: Please explain your stuff in more detail if is it possible then also add code here...

Comment: My experience with PeopleSoft and SOAP UI is that you have to add the SOAP Headers manually.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's the only solution I can see now. Is anybody done the authentication on NODE level? Will it be good to do? Thanks in Advance for suggestions.